# how to set shared weights for different neural networks among different Python processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, neural-network, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement asynchronous version of deep Q-learning algorithm with Python, which requires a shared neural network among different processes for asynchronous updates.  I know that it is pretty difficult to share object itself in Python due to GIL, and I found that it may be possible to simply share its weights using https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array.

But the problem is this Array object is that it is 1D and does not support `reshape()` and `flatten()` operations, which means every time I want to copy local weights to global ones, I have to get all weights, reshape them and convert them to this Array.  And when I want to copy weights back, I need to do opposite conversion, which would be quite computationally expensive.  I am wondering if there are good ways to directly integrate some shared arrays (does not need to be this Array object) into the weights of neural networks so that every time when I call `update()` it would modify the global weights directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to allocate the memory for the numpy array using some kind of shared memory space. The `multiprocessing.Array` object is actually a really good way of achieving this. Then you can create a view of the `Array` object using numpy and all the views will share memory. You can do this once in your main process, or have each child process do it once before beginning it's work. I've written an example using the first method. Keep in mind that this is in no way "process safe" so you'll need to use your own locking.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
import numpy as np
import ctypes

shape = (10, 2)
_shared_array = Array(ctypes.c_double, np.prod(shape), lock=False)
shared_array = np.frombuffer(_shared_array, dtype='double').reshape(shape)

def target_func(index, value):
    shared_array[index, :] = value

p = Pool(4)
for i in range(10):
    p.apply_async(target_func, args=(i, i**2))

p.close()
p.join()

print shared_array
# [[  0.   0.]
#  [  1.   1.]
#  [  4.   4.]
#  [  9.   9.]
#  [ 16.  16.]
#  [ 25.  25.]
#  [ 36.  36.]
#  [ 49.  49.]
#  [ 64.  64.]
#  [ 81.  81.]]
```